# error labelling axis of plot using Ecdf

Tags: r

I am attempting to plot a graph using the code below:

```
Require(Hmisc)
Ecdf(ceac_primary,xlab="axis label",xlim=c(5000,50000),q=c(0.9,0.1),
ylab="Probability of Success",main="CEAC")
```

Where ceac_primary is a data frame with 1 variable of 90k observations.

When I include the 'xlab="axis label"' I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in Ecdf.default(v, group = group, weights = weights, normwt = normwt,  : 
formal argument "xlab" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

However if I exclude the x axis label part of the code, it plots the graph fine.

Is this a known problem, and if so, are there alternative ways to plot an x axis label?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging around in the source code for `Ecdf.data.frame` (the method that is called when passing a data.frame to `Ecdf`), it looks like that function creates an object that is later passed to the `xlab` argument. Therefore, `xlab` is not expected as a user-supplied argument when running `Ecdf` with a data.frame. Here's the code that creates the object `lab` that gets passed to `xlab` within `Ecdf.data.frame`:

```
lab <- if (vnames == "names") 
        nam[j]
    else label(v, units = TRUE, plot = TRUE, default = nam[j])
```

Then `Ecdf` is called with `xlab = lab`, but also any arguments in the elipses of `Ecdf.data.frame` are also passed to `Ecdf`. Since `xlab` is not a formal argument of `Ecdf.data.frame`, this is why you get your error.

To get around it, try either of the following:

Convert your data.frame to a vector of the appropriate class (numeric, I presume), and then run

```
Ecdf(ceac_primary_Vec, xlab = "axis label")
```

Or, you can create a label for the one column in your data.frame using the `label` function in the `Hmisc` package. If that column is called `myCol`, you can run

```
label(ceac_primary$myCol) <- "axis label"
Ecdf(ceac_primary)
```

And that should get your axis label printing correctly.